# Запрос SQL как добавить результаты выборок в третью

Tags: sql, sql-server

Пробовал join но встал вопрос а как добавлять в третью таблицу строки от результата.
Есть две таблицы.

```
CREATE TABLE [dbo].[Class1] (
    [Oid]                 UNIQUEIDENTIFIER ROWGUIDCOL NOT NULL,
    [METHODID]            SMALLINT         NULL,
    [DESCRIPTION]         NVARCHAR (100)   NULL,
    [TEXTDESCRIPTION]     NVARCHAR (100)   NULL,
    [METHODTYPEID]        NVARCHAR (100)   NULL,
    [OptimisticLockField] INT              NULL,
    [GCRecord]            INT              NULL,
    CONSTRAINT [PK_Class1] PRIMARY KEY CLUSTERED ([Oid] ASC)
);
CREATE TABLE [dbo].[Class3] (
    [Oid]                 UNIQUEIDENTIFIER ROWGUIDCOL NOT NULL,
    [TESTID]              SMALLINT         NULL,
    [DESCRIPTION]         NVARCHAR (250)   NULL,
    [SHORTNAME]           NVARCHAR (250)   NULL,
    [SHORTDESCRIPTION]    NVARCHAR (4000)  NULL,
    [TESTTYPEID]          SMALLINT         NULL,
    [OptimisticLockField] INT              NULL,
    [GCRecord]            INT              NULL,
    [CL1]                 UNIQUEIDENTIFIER NULL,
    CONSTRAINT [PK_Class3] PRIMARY KEY CLUSTERED ([Oid] ASC),
    CONSTRAINT [FK_Class3_CL1] FOREIGN KEY ([CL1]) REFERENCES [dbo].[Class1] ([Oid]) NOT FOR REPLICATION
);
```

Так выглядят результаты запросов

```
select Oid from Class1

97588752-C528-4B43-9A15-00A0E5083609
9BEF7A31-1935-4C54-837F-019BF71FC6E2
02D4E121-1BAA-4801-8A8E-02317601AA67
8B5DA090-A525-445E-B041-02A31887F7BF
F011432F-D2B4-46DE-9411-030556343B91
2AF774CB-22EB-4DF4-B412-059843EA88CD



select Oid from Class3

3FA98E37-B0B7-4BD7-95D0-E666C4848930
B8DCB573-B0D1-4B2F-8E5D-E7AD0BCA941F
DE013183-2370-4585-B741-E8C26EE69A8A
F74D2B69-8420-4C70-BA89-EACBF33CAB18
4D696BF2-CCEC-44D5-BBE5-EB12612E3396
8FF70DAB-E28C-4B4B-8904-EC7B2AC10A0F
```

Есть третья таблица

```
CREATE TABLE [dbo].[Class3Class3s_Class1Class1s] (
    [Class1s]             UNIQUEIDENTIFIER NULL,
    [Class3s]             UNIQUEIDENTIFIER NULL,
    [OID]                 UNIQUEIDENTIFIER ROWGUIDCOL NOT NULL,
    [OptimisticLockField] INT              NULL,
    CONSTRAINT [PK_Class3Class3s_Class1Class1s] PRIMARY KEY CLUSTERED ([OID] ASC),
    CONSTRAINT [FK_Class3Class3s_Class1Class1s_Class1s] FOREIGN KEY ([Class1s]) REFERENCES [dbo].[Class1] ([Oid]) NOT FOR REPLICATION,
    CONSTRAINT [FK_Class3Class3s_Class1Class1s_Class3s] FOREIGN KEY ([Class3s]) REFERENCES [dbo].[Class3] ([Oid]) NOT FOR REPLICATION
);
```

В эту таблицу мне нужно добавить результаты двух выборок плюс получить для поля OID уникальное значение.
Подскажите как сделать такую конструкцию. Я пробовал джойнить, но как потом добавлять это все в третью таблицу не знаю. Можно ли это сделать все в одном запросе. Или все  это делать через параметры в Insert.
В итоге хочется получить такой результат.

```
Class1s                              Class3s                              Oid
c57ffe53-e6f9-4f44-99a2-007d7fbc9395 66de7a26-b81d-4cfb-9139-00d8a73acaad 9baef9ca-962e-42d1-8e98-72632303f970
```

Comment: *В итоге хочется получить такой результат.* Откуда взяты эти 3 значения (ни одного из них нет в показанном выше выводе запросов)? Почему именно это значение Class1s сделано парным именно этому значению Class3s?

Comment: @Akina написано же `FOREIGN KEY ([CL1]) REFERENCES [dbo].[Class1]`

Comment: @Akina Спасибо за ответ, вид результата показан только в качестве примера. такое парное значение это таблица связи Многие ко многим, которое реализовано в определенном приложении.

Comment: @ВикторЕвлампьев FK гарантируют ссылочную целостность, но допускают множественные ссылки (1:М). И что делать в случае дубликатов по CL1?

Comment: *это таблица связи Многие ко многим* Я верно понимаю, что нужно создать все возможные пары? Но в такой структуре прямая связь таблиц может не соответствовать связи через связующую таблицу... *вид результата показан только в качестве примера* Пожалуйста, исправьте это - все показываемые значения должны соответствовать друг другу. Для устранения неоднозначностей.

Comment: @Akina да нужно создать все пары

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> нужно создать все пары

```
INSERT INTO Class3Class3s_Class1Class1s (Class1s, Class3s, OID)
SELECT Class1.OID, Class3.OID, NEWID()
FROM Class1, Class3
WHERE Class1.OID = Class3.CL1
/* ну или
FROM Class1
INNER JOIN Class3 ON Class1.OID = Class3.CL1
*/
```

Comment: Спасибо , сейчас попробую

Comment: @VladimrVladimirovoch И добавьте в структуру CHECK CONSTRAINT, который исключит несоответствие в кольце референсов.

Comment: Спасибо то что нужно

Answer (score 1):

Во-первых, я бы советовал Вам оформить в транзакцию.
То, что Вы ищете выглядит приблизительно вот так:

SELECT полe1 из Join, полe2 из Join, NEWID()  INTO Class3Class3s_Class1Class1s